# More needs to be done against anti-semitic posts on Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, offensive

Today, there was *yet again* an [anti-semitic question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/45217) on Stack Exchange, about Nazi Germany's actions against the Jews.

What do I mean by "yet again"? Well, in this [Skeptics meta question](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4324) from February this year, I noted that half of the "helpful" flags on questions on Skeptics.SE were about the holocaust, and approximately half of the remainder were about Jews or Nazi Germany. And the majority of the questions I flagged for holocaust denial were around for more than two hours, ranging from 6 minutes to 8 hours, 20 minutes.

And is it just Skeptics.SE? Nope, here's a quick sample from History.SE. [One](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/43621), [two](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/39112), [three](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/34600), [four](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/34312), [five](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/29097) - and that's not going all the way back in my flag history. There have been some problematic content on Politics.SE, but usually it's less blatantly antisemitic, apart from [this one](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/4562).

I don't think it's a problem with diamond moderators. They've tended to do the right thing, and the fact that it happens on more than one site indicates it's probably not an issue with a particular moderator. I also believe that the smoke detector tries to deal with this.

I don't think it's an unsolvable problem - it seems to be the a very small handful of people or groups posting the same hateful garbage again and again every few months, for example compare [Were Nazis favorable to zionism?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/45217) and https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/44757.

For the avoidance of doubt, I want Stack Exchange to act on all bigotry, and I've flagged on a variety of bigotries (people who are bigoted against Jews are also bigoted against other groups), but this is the particular ongoing problem I've faced in my experience as a non-diamond-moderator high-rep user.

Comment: In general, there's a practical technical limit here -- six humans who know how to flag as abusive need to actually read those kinds of posts before they can be removed. Smaller sites, it's gonna be harder to remove stuff like that quickly, within the system as designed. How long do these posts tend to stay up, in your experience?

Comment: I don't have 10k on History, but the Skeptics posts you linked were handled by the community within hours of posting.  What would you like to see?  That those posts are handled within minutes, or that they are (semi-)automatically prevented from being posted in the first place?

Comment: What kind of "more"? Examples: They are *deleted!* On History the kind of primitive AS content as Qs is usually gone in minutes, usually disappears before I *can* take action. The more problematic thing is when AS posts *remain* (and some *do;* Holocaust denial, relativism, primary and secondary antisemitism) Since my comments, flags etc on some of these were denied or resulted in 'helpful' non-action, I'd like you to find examples *you* identify as such that are still standing. (Sidenote: I'd be almost for these posts remain visible, but with oblivion votes next to them)

Comment: +1 Thank you for bringing this issue to meta! It's something that really needs to be addressed. And I think it's not only a problem with obvious trolls, but also how antisemitism of established users is handled (or not handled). Just as an example: the user complaining on your linked politics.SE post that Jews control the media, that Hitler wasn't an antisemite, and that Jews brought the Holocaust on themselves is not banned.

Comment: They are almost all deleted already so where's the problem exactly?

Comment: @tim The problem with politics.SE is that mods allow users with years-long problematic behaviour to continue to crap over the site. See e.g. [Why are people who unapologetically and repeatedly post racist drivel not banned for extended periods of time?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3596) IIRC they were banned for *a week*(!) after denying the holocaust on that Q. I eventually just deleted my account as the platform has become one of misinformation and toxicity. It's the worst site on SE by far, and has been for many years. It should be killed and (possibly) rebooted.

Comment: Andrew - what, exactly, are you requesting? Flags need a human at the other end to address the issue. Whether it's a mod to delete the post, or multiple members whose cumulative flags/delete votes will get rid of it as well.  The bots do ok, but still not at the level of humans. FWIW even if individuals get banned, it's little effort for them to get another IP address, and new member ID.

Comment: Either way, the response on Politics.SE seems unique to just that site; and the responses on other sites has been significantly more appropriate from what I've seen.

Comment: Martin, that's another story, I don't spend enough time at Politics to see that. Those accts should be deleted, but the person will still return.

Comment: @ChristineH.Richards The high volume combined with a sometimes slow response time means that skeptics.SE for example has at least hosted Holocaust denial for 75 hours in the last couple of years (just taken from OPs and my flags; the actual number is likely considerably higher). This is getting to a point where it's not acceptable anymore, and where a technical solution might be helpful.

Comment: @MartinTournoij Good point, I haven't had such severe problems elsewhere. On politics.Se, I've seen multiple users personally harassed (me included) and hardcore antisemites and racists receiving no or only a week long ban for it. I feel that it's gotten a bit better in recent months, but maybe I don't notice the harassment as much because I'm not as active there anymore.

Comment: @tim 75 hours in 8 years of existence? Less than 0.1% of Skeptics entire existence. I call that a success history. Despite the obvious target one would expect more denialism.

Comment: @tim - that's not acceptable. Becoming a Mod was an agreement to regular visits, at the very least a daily stop. The 4 mods here are from around the world, so, on average, there should be a mod visit within 8-12 hrs max. Is demanding sub-4hr response reasonable? Probably not. But, over 16 hrs isn't acceptable.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer No, sorry for the misunderstanding. I didn't mean that one question was up 75 hours, but [combined](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4324/) the 26 questions me and OP flagged were up 75 hours (with an average of 3 hours and a maximum of 8 hours per question).

Comment: @tim - 3-8 hrs makes sense, no? The humans are doing fine. The real question is whether the bot can be better trained.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Sure, it makes sense, and I agree that the mods and users are doing their best in these cases. But given the current rate of these questions, the end result is still not great. I don't know if there are good technical solutions for this, but I think the situation is bad enough that it's worth talking about them.

Comment: It's simple for holocaust denial, because the bar for this being a reason for deletion is low. Now, good luck with sorting out possible denials of other https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genocides_in_history . However, you mentioned how long the posts had been visible. Usually, "time before deletion" is not an indicator for how bad a question is. Can you say anything about the *vote counts* that these questions had when they were deleted? I cannot see the questions any more, but ... just because a question is considered "offensive" or "uncomfortable" does not mean that it is not a "good question".

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer The mods are as much a (non)problem as users. Such content (I'd support to keep on Skeptics for open-to-see destruction by argument) if undesirable, can be flagged and downvoted by users. Was it 6? Having them agree on content being abusive will delete this as well. Mods then only needed to come by once a week to possibly undelete if that was in error. // The main problem I see under current regime: way too many *do not see it, don't ack on it being AS* even upvote that ick. Meaning we need to educate a big chunk of users in a way that we surely cannot train a bot!

Comment: @MartinTournoij [Thank God, I thought it was just me](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/4054/revisions)

Comment: Are we just talking about low quality, new account questions that wouldn’t fly even if they were about anything else? Or the rest, which could also include upvoted questions asked by otherwise well respected users? (see also [here](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3843/37236))

Comment: Could you provide screenshots of these deleted questions? Notions of what counts as "antisemitic" are pretty diverse, and since only a tiny proportion of the network's users are >10k on History or Skeptics, most of us are left to guess at the nature of the content you're objecting to. In particular, it's not clear to me whether we're talking about posts that indicate some kind of anti-Jewish animus, here, or just clumsily-asked or ill-informed questions about the Haavara Agreement or details of the Holocaust.

Comment: @Mark I think that screenshotting isn’t the best of ideas, but I’m not fully opposed to it. However, I’d like you to reflect on the fact that they’ve been marked as helpful by moderators, have been deleted, make up a large proportion of my helpful rude and abusive question flags, make up a large number of questions overall, and have been described as a problem by other users, and decide whether it’s plausible to attribute it predominantly to over-sensitivity to questions which were asked in good faith.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Well, even granting the points you list, it's still plausible they were asked in good faith, and that needn't imply "over-sensitivity" (to use your phrasing) on behalf of anyone involved; perhaps (I speculate blindly) the mods validated the flags simply because they were awful questions, or because they were bad questions specifically on sensitive issues likely to cause offence. But even if they *are* bad-faith, that could just as well mean either disingenuously naive questions about sensitive topics, or manifestos about wiping out the Jews, and I'm still curious about which.

Comment: @MarkAmery I've posted some screenshots at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335671/38765 . You may want to see it quickly, in case someone decides to delete them.

Comment: To illustrate what to me seems to be a much bigger problem than quickly deleted stuff, please haed on [over](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4076/does-claiming-someone-is-dog-whistling-go-against-assuming-good-faith) and please way in there. It looks to me that a sizeable portion of users have issues with identifying dog whistles?

Comment: There's not much anyone could do, other than flagging and deletion, for vileness posted by new users. They will always be a problem; all we can do is reduce its magnitude. Or do we have a problem we long term users who repeatedly post bad stuff? (One comment above says so) Because that us much worse.

Comment: @Raedwald *That* is what concerns me. Over time you realize that quite a few users post occasionally *horrible stuff* (not always). But as long as the rep is above ~500 it takes *quite* a while for that content to be called out; if. As long as rep is positive and the egregious stuff either hidden, dog whistling or intermittently enough, this grows. Have few examples ready. What is there left to do, if you *do* comment, flag, DV, raise in chat and meta and *only then* people start to see it? Do that all the time?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

A voluntary organization consisting of passionate Stack Exchange users have built a bot named SmokeDetector, aimed at these posts that should be red-flagged (spam or abusive).

We're aware of this "holocaust" troll and this very word has been on our watchlist. Once the SmokeDetector bot reports such posts, we'll come and flag them to death quickly.

If you see such posts in the future, you're free to inform us in [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) chatroom and we'll handle it.

Comment: Thanks for adding "Haavara" to the list today upon my message in the chatroom.

Comment: As a heads up, the post I was mentioning wasn't detected by the bot.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Yes. A bot is a bot, and it's been missing borderline posts from time to time. That very post didn't contain any "sensitive" keywords (like *holocaust*), so it slipped through our checks. We rely on users reporting posts manually in this case, and once we notice them, we take actions accordingly.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm We're happy to get additional ways to detect spam/trolling, including what's being discussed here. Additional suggestions for things (e.g. text patterns) the SmokeDetector should be looking for are appreciated. If there are more complex detections you think would be of benefit, you're also welcome to submit PRs to the [SmokeDetector GitHub repo.](https://git.io/vgx7b). A significant issue for us is that we only have so many people volunteering their time. If you, or anyone else, wants to help pitch-in and review posts which SmokeDetector reports, that would be quite helpful.

Comment: I don’t think it should be incumbent on ordinary users to check for new keywords to supply to SmokeDetector. In addition, some ordinary users don’t have the rep to see posts they’ve flagged once they’ve been deleted - I didn’t have the rep required to see content in either history or politics, I can’t remember which. Maybe paid staff ought to be doing this.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm don't worry too much. If it gets too noisy, the knobs can be turned to look for words combinations. Also, SD has a dashboard where we can review accuracy of the rules used.

Comment: Is there any statistics available on how long these posts live on average?

Comment: @fredsbend Thanks. Hours feels still a bit long to me for such offensive content. I would very much like to support any initiatives to shorten the time even more. When I flag something for moderation I usually get an action within minutes (on StackOverflow). Of course Skeptics is much, much smaller.

Comment: @Trilarion the median is slightly above 2 hours when I checked in February and posted about it in the Skeptics meta post I linked to in my question.

Answer (score 12):

[We've already hashed this out on Skeptics Meta](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4324/11643), so readers here should check it out there first.

One thing I think we need here is perspective to see what *kind* of problem may exist that we can solve. These trollish hate things will always be posted. The point of trolling is to be offensive while not breaking the rules. They  get posted and will probably always be. That leaves us with *repeatedly* downvoting, closing, and deleting. All these hate posts get handled *in this way* quickly. But when we see *repeated* human action our thoughts should lean toward efficiency and automation. Can we make a computer accurately imitate a human in these instances, without causing adverse effects? Can we save ourselves some time and trouble?  I'm all for automating human tasks, but only if data supports the need and it can be designed without actually creating more exceptions and need for human intervention.

The Smoke Detector is a neat tool, helping to speed up *human* response. I worry however that in these types of things, nuance in language and intent is near impossible to condense into a script, so keeping review *human* is almost always preferable.

If SE could actually put some data together we can see if we should try to automate in the first place (ie determine if it would reserve human effort). *How* to automate is another question, and one I'm not convinced we could even do. It depends on what the data shows.

So to be clear, I don't think we're solving an *offensive content* problem, namely because ot human review processes are cleaning it up pretty quickly. So if there's a problem, it's a bulge in overall human effort. A computer might save us all a lot of time.

Comment: Did you have a particular one in mind? Link?

Comment: Yes. Sorry. I see. No need to bring it here. Can this met be closed as a dupe of that one? Prob, not?

Comment: You yourself suggested going to SE staff with this. It's my understanding that meta.skeptics.SE is definitely not the right way to reach them, so OP opened a question on this meta. It might not be the best way to reach them, but now complaining that OP tried this seems odd. Also, my experience is that the Holocaust questions make up at least your suggested 20% of spam, likely more. Getting actual stats on this from SE staff would definitely be interesting.

Comment: And if some research into this shows that it is indeed the problem we think it is, something like "holds for moderation" seems like a reasonable idea. I'm sure those could also be bypassed, but if it would catch at least some percentage of these questions, that would already be something.

Comment: @tim These 'new ideas' *may* be interesting, if the problem is shown to be *bigger* than the examples. Bigger=posts with staying power, despite AS in them. I second fredsbend in that quickly deleted posts cannot be the problem you meant. The problem I see are only those that remain online despite having AS content to varying degrees. Those that get perhaps 1–2 deserved flags and then a mod decides 'nah' & moves on. On H:SE the resident denialist tries his shtick once a week and disappears from view before a feed is updated. How do we tackle thin or thickly veiled AS that *is* online?

Answer (score 5):

Posting this as an answer, so that it will not be in the edit history of the question, because people were casting doubt on what the questions were like.

This was the most recent question about the treatment of Jews by Nazi Germany.

> [image: Screenshot of the recent question]

You can see that it is extremely similar to the second most recent one I encountered, and from a while ago. If data from this had been fed to the smoke detector, it would have detected the most recent one, but it did not get detected.

> [image: Screenshot of an earlier one]

These questions were redundant, because there’s already a well answered question [Did Hitler support zionism?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/32677/did-hitler-support-zionism)

This post was around for 8 hours, 20 minutes.

> [image: A post left for long]

This post was around for 6 hours, 28 minutes.

> [image: Another post left for long]

If any moderator wishes to delete answer, go ahead. I do not mind. I hope this is sufficient for people to see that there are bad faith, offensive, questions occurring.

Comment: If someone defines Zionism as the repopulation of Israel with Jews, (a definition that may have been used in the 1930s) then it becomes a reasonable question to ask.

Comment: It's quite possible to ask a good-faith question about Nazis and Zionism.  The Holocaust was not the only proposed solution for what the Nazis termed "the Jewish Question"; a number of options for expelling Jews from Greater Germany were also proposed.  The best-known of these was the [Madagascar Plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madagascar_Plan), but I wouldn't be surprised if "send them back to Israel" was also floated.

Comment: Being from Germany, I hesitate to write this but ... if the "duplicate" question was problematic, then the dupe-target should also be, and a link to wikipedia shouldn't be a problem either. I guess one problem is the suggestive way how they (mainly the last ones) are phrased, right? Otherwise, I think these are just questions that are ...\*ehrm\* let's say ... calling them "very low quality" would give them undue credit. And they *should* be flushed down the toilet - but only for exactly this reason.

Comment: @Marco13 If you follow both, dupe and target, then you should realise that 'target' *does* answer the dupe (if taken at face value = assuming good faith) and that the "dupe" is really a primitive pushy and soap boxy piece. And **No.** They are not really just low quality. The short WP link thing is just *raising awareness* for a tangential fact (let's say: superseded by actual history? Just reading the Wp page given shows the absurdity of the goal of the question) that's used out of context for conspiracy theories. Most probably a 'constructed trap', poor as it is. Ample reasons for deletion.

Comment: @Marco13 The “dupe” maybe phrased in bad faith, but the target for the dupe is ideally a legitimate, good faith question. IF one finds a possible dupe target that is *also* offensive, then both ought to go. The answers on this page show that abusive posts of the type discussed are being actively curated and moderated, however, so I don’t think you need be overly concerned about abusive targets.

Comment: My main point was that the questions obviously are as bad as they can get, but not more than that (even though it's clear what the questions are aiming at ... maybe I'm just blunted by the more obvious stuff). However, I'm neither a historian nor a moderator, and certainly don't want to argue about that. You're gonna sort that out, I guess.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I don't see anything here that would convince me these were posted with any kind of antisemitic motive. I can *easily* imagine a naive teenager stumbling across claims on the internet about the Holocaust that they find shocking, not knowing how to fact-check them, and ending up at Skeptics. It's not obvious to me that I'm seeing anything here but run-of-the-mill *bad questions*, of the sort that some sites in the network (like Stack Overflow) have flowing in by the minute. Nor is it obvious to me that any remedy is needed beyond those applied to other bad questions.

Comment: @Mark not even the “more witnesses for aliens than the holocaust” looks bad-faith to you?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm it *looks* bad faith. But I'm still a long way from being sure. People genuinely believe stupider things.

Answer (score 2):

Individual questions seem to be resolved as quickly as much be expected. The only way to speed things up should be paid moderators working across the network.

However, I do think that some of the concern might be that these questions are not made in good faith (i.e., a serious historical question about an unpleasant topic). Bad behavior like that should be grounds for a moderator warning (no idea how you would phrase it). A pattern of such behavior should be grounds for a ban (user or IP) under the CoC as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to deal with bigotry in general is to take everything said at face value and potentially answer it if it is interesting enough or downvote it if not, or if a claim is trivially falsifiable. (Note that I find it especially valuable to sincerely answer even bad faith Holocaust denials. I have personally learned a lot by taking seemingly stupid or provocative questions seriously and answering them best I could. It never hurts to have a reality check.<sup>1</sup> Since the claims on Nazis and the Holocaust are probably factually resembling each other the answers will be readily available anyway.)

One of the reasons for my opinion is that "bad faith" is difficult to prove and will often result in false positives (see the recent mod ban).

It appears to me that the rules applying to all posts are sufficient to deal with provocative troll posts, including this particular flavor: Bad posts are downvoted, offensive posts are flagged and removed. Does that create an unsustainable burden on the moderators?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Have you ever tried to explain to some skeptic in detail the earth's thermodynamic equilibrium mechanism and how within this framework the greenhouse effect works (CO2 vs. H2O absorption bands, temperature gradient in the atmosphere, sun activity and earth orbit effects etc.)?</sub>

Comment: FYI, there was already a question covering the Haavara agreement. https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/32677/did-hitler-support-zionism